# select all input tags that have a type of number

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to select all input tags with attribute type="number"
i tried but its not working

`````
   document.getElementById("inactive").setAttribute("disabled")
}   else {
    document.getElementById('inactive').removeAttribute("disabled")
}````
`````

Comment: try `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```js
const elements1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
console.log(elements1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" />
    <input type="number" id="age" />
    <input type="number" id="age1" />

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` fetches only a single element (ID is *intended* to be a unique identifier).

When you have multiple elements, you usually use the `class` attribute to group them.

In your case, you want to select inputs with a specific attribute. For that, you need to use a `selector` (like in css) to target inputs of type=number.

The way you can do that in javascript is by using `document.querySelectorAll`, which lets you grab all elements matching a specific selector pattern (in this case, `input[type="number"]`).

See the code below for an example

```js
window.onload = () => {
  // Fetch all inputs of type=number
  const numberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');

  // Loop over each input element and do something with them.
  numberInputs.forEach(element => element.setAttribute('disabled', true));
};
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1">
<input type="number" value="2">
<input type="number" value="3">

<br>
<input type="text" value="this won't be selected">
```